# What is the recommended way to handle cross-site duplicates

Tags: discussion

I have asked the question [OS X: Blurry Beamer presentations on Sierra / High Sierra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431423/os-x-blurry-beamer-presentations-on-sierra-high-sierra), which is about workarounds for the broken PDF rendering on recent versions of OS X that bite especially those of us, who are presenting with LaTeX `beamer`.

A few days later (spotted by user samcarter) the question [What PDF Viewer can be used to present slides on High Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325622/what-pdf-viewer-can-be-used-to-present-slides-on-high-sierra) appeared on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) (the Apple users SE site), which is about the very same problem and setting and, thus, would qualify as a duplicate.

As a helpful action for others seeking for advice, I had duplicated the answer of user DG' to Ask Different and linked to the original. However, such kind of redundancy is generally discouraged at SE sites. On the other hand, both, the question and the answer (arguably) fits the scope of both sites.

So how to handle cross-site dupes? If either one gets removed, will there be the common "duplicate" box pointing to the related question on the other site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no real solution for cross-site duplicates.

My personal opinion: leave it as it is, the duplication of the information seems fine in this case. Technically one could argue, that the question about a viewer problem is probably off-topic for tex.stackexchange, BUT:

- we already have many other questions about viewer problems, so it is probably not necessary to change the course right now
- the good answer you got here speaks for itself. Before you posted your answer there, the question on ask.different just got (now deleted) answers like "use openoffice instead" or comments like "convert the pdf to powerpoint", which I don't perceive as good solutions to present a high quality pdf as it is produced by latex.

Comment: Yes, Apple communities tend to be like that... To be honest, the much higher chance to get a *real* answer was the point asking here :-)